# ggplot2: Getting a color legend to appear using stat_function() in a for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add some distributions to a plot using the stat_function(). I am able to do this successfully with the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length=n+1)
  hcl(h=hues, l=65, c=100)[1:n]
}

plotMixMdlComps <- function(x, mu, sigma, lam) {
  lam * dnorm(x, mu, sigma )
}

clusterDf <- data.frame(cluster = c(6,5,4,8,0,7,3),
                        mu = c(0.73908779, 0.43233777, 0.28041006, 0.35627709,
                               0.09330585, 0.18250758, 0.56998734),
                        sigma = c(0.06472281, 0.03218096, 0.02779751,
                                  0.02208605, 0.02716692, 0.01890661,
                                  0.02995616),
                        lambda = c(0.042749908, 0.254485536, 0.205602343,
                                   0.404705236, 0.061058220, 0.024166972,
                                   0.007231783))

cols <- nrow(clusterDf) %>%
  gg_color_hue()

inDf <- data.frame(x = c(0,1))

p <- ggplot(inDf, aes(x)) +
  xlim(0,1) +
  ylim(0,10)

for (i in 1:nrow(clusterDf)) {
  p <- p + stat_function(geom = "line", fun = plotMixMdlComps,
                         arg = list(clusterDf[i, "mu"],
                                    clusterDf[i, "sigma"],
                                    clusterDf[i, "lambda"]),
                         lwd = 1.5, colour = cols[i])
}

p
```

This generates a figure like this:

[image]

But I want to have a legend to appear. After reading online, it appears that I could just wrap the colour parameter in aes() like this:

```
p <- ggplot(inDf, aes(x)) +
  xlim(0,1) +
  ylim(0,10)

for (i in 1:nrow(clusterDf)) {
  p <- p + stat_function(geom = "line", fun = plotMixMdlComps,
                         arg = list(clusterDf[i, "mu"],
                                    clusterDf[i, "sigma"],
                                    clusterDf[i, "lambda"]),
                         lwd = 1.5, aes(colour = cols[i]))
}
p
```

But this ends up generating a plot like this,

[image]

I am thinking this has to do with NSE (I still have trouble understanding it) where it only "resolves" the cols[i] when it is called. So every stat_function ends up resolving to have the same cols[i] which should be cols[7]. Is there a way to get ggplot to "resolve" this immediately instead of waiting for p to be called?

Thanks,

Comment: ggplot2 is designed to work with long-form data. Reshape your data so that there is a column "variable" (with values "mu", "sigma", and "lambda"), and a column "value" with the corresponding values. (In your example it should have 21 rows.) Then map the "variable" column to the "color" aesthetic, and the legend will appear automatically.

Comment: @krlmlr Not sure how to make this work with a stat_function()? The plotMixMdlComps() function takes the values from each row of the clusterDf to generate the distribution. If I melt it, how do I stat_function to retrieve the needed values for each cluster?

Comment: Sorry, read only half of your question. But the general idea remains the same: Create a data frame in long form, using your `plot...` function and some `x` values (not too few, not too many), that contains a row for each point on the line you want to plots. (Contains `length(x) * 7` rows now.) Then, use simply `aes(x=x, y=y, color=cluster)` for this entire data frame, and don't use a loop to build the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help on `stat_function` has an example for showing two functions in the same plot. It also adds `stat_function` twice and specifies explicit colours and no automatic legend is generated:

```
f <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 10)), aes(x))
f + stat_function(fun = sin, colour = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = cos, colour = "blue")
```

Thus, I suspect that plotting several functions with a legend is not within the scope of `stat_function`.

Following  krlmlr's remark you could create a data set as follows:

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.01)
names(clusterDf)[4]<-"lam"
fun_data <- lapply(1:nrow(clusterDf),function(i) {
               args <- clusterDf[i,-1]
               data.frame(cluster=clusterDf$cluster[i],
                          x=x,
                          y=do.call(plotMixMdlComps,c(list(x=x),args))
               )
}) %>% bind_rows
```

This can now be plotted directly with ggplot:

```
ggplot(fun_data,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=as.factor(cluster))) + geom_line(lwd=1.5)
```

This lets ggplot pick the colours for you. If you want to use the colours that you specified (which are, in your situation, identical to those that ggplot picks), you can add `scale_colour_manual(values=cols)` to the plot.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you could also create the plot data using `mdply` from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
x <- seq(0,1,0.01)
names(clusterDf)[4]<-"lam"
fun_data <- mdply(clusterDf,function(cluster,mu,sigma,lam) {
    data.frame(cluster=cluster,
               x=x,
               y=plotMixMdlComps(x,mu,sigma,lam)
    )
}) %>% bind_rows
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks so much for your suggestion and code. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since the original post and much has changed in `ggplot2`. Aesthetic mappings can now also be applied to programmatically in `stat_function`, either by using Tidy-evaluated quasi-quotations within `aes()` or by using `aes_()`. [See release note of ggplot2 3.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.0.0).